# impossible to access area amministraotre magento after changing server

Tags: php, mysql, magento, magento-1.7

I imported Magetno 1.7 on my server and I when I try to access the administrator I always get this error:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:36:"Value '188,000000' has to be numeric";i:1;s:4781:"#0 /var/www/clients/client1
/web8/web/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Column/Renderer/Currency.php(63): Zend_Currency->toCurrency('188,000000')
#1 /var/www/clients/client1/web8/web/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Column.php(128): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Currency->render(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order))
#2 /var/www/clients/client1/web8/web/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/dashboard/grid.phtml(53): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column->getRowField(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order))
#3 /var/www/clients/client1/web8/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/client...')
#4 /var/www/clients/client1/web8/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#5 /var/www/clients/client1/web8/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#6 /var/www/clients/client1/web8/web/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#7 /var/www/clients/client1/web8/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#8 /var/www/clients/client1/web8/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(582): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#9 /var/www/clients/client1/web8/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(526): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('lastOrders', true)
#10 /var/www/clients/client1/web8/web/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/dashboard/index.phtml(105): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('lastOrders')
#11 /var/www/clients/client1/web8/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/client...')
#12 /var/www/clients/client1/web8/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#13 /var/www/clients/client1/web8/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#14 /var/www/clients/client1/web8/web/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#15 /var/www/clients/client1/web8/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#16 /var/www/clients/client1/web8/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#17 /var/www/clients/client1/web8/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#18 /var/www/clients/client1/web8/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(582): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#19 /var/www/clients/client1/web8/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(526): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
#20 /var/www/clients/client1/web8/web/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page.phtml(74): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
#21 /var/www/clients/client1/web8/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/client...')
#22 /var/www/clients/client1/web8/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#23 /var/www/clients/client1/web8/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#24 /var/www/clients/client1/web8/web/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#25 /var/www/clients/client1/web8/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#26 /var/www/clients/client1/web8/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#27 /var/www/clients/client1/web8/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#28 /var/www/clients/client1/web8/web/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php(43): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#29 /var/www/clients/client1/web8/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Adminhtml_DashboardController->indexAction()
#30 /var/www/clients/client1/web8/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#31 /var/www/clients/client1/web8/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#32 /var/www/clients/client1/web8/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#33 /var/www/clients/client1/web8/web/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#34 /var/www/clients/client1/web8/web/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#35 {main}";s:3:"url";s:70:"/index.php/admin/dashboard/index/key/fbfc81d4213ac288f3e8d0205c2c5254/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this my problem?

Comment: I'm not soooo old, so you can write the question in smaller font

Comment: You should be more descriptive with what you did.  This is probably better suited for [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) but they will be very pissed off if you don't explain (as best you can) what you did to reach this state

Comment: I made a compressed copy of the site and a dump in sql.gz.
With ftp I downloaded the two files compressed my mac and then I reloaded the two files on my new server.
On the new server the site frontend works fine but when I log in I mywebsite.com/admin and then I insert user and password I have suffered a mistake by Magento.
In var / report is written all over the piece of code that I posted.
I thought that this error could depend on the server so I did some other tests on two other servers debian+ipsconfig+nginx and I've always had the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Look like you have a number format error :

```
"Value '188,000000' has to be numeric"
```

**188.000000 is numeric**

**188,000000 is not.**